# How can I fix a strange formatting problem on a particular page on my Gantry website?

Tags: joomla-3.x, bootstrap, gantry

I have a strange issue on a Gantry 4 website where I updated the content of a page and the menu title and alias and this seems to have broken the template layout.

The content is pushed to the left but only this one page is affected.

I have tried simplifying the article content to a single space in case I had introduced some invalid code but this makes no difference.

Renaming the menu alias so that it does not contain "span" in the text seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took quite a while to find but Bootstrap includes some default styling as follows:

```
[class*="span"] {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 30px;
  min-height: 1px;
}
```

This unfortunately conflicts with Gantry which adds a class based on the menu alias to the `body` CSS selector.

To fix the problem, I created a custom CSS file and added the following code to override the Bootstrap styling:

```
[class*="span"] {
  float: inherit;
  margin-left: inherit;
  min-height: inherit;
}
```